# Use of xHCI driver and USB_STORAGE driver

Tags: linux-kernel, usb, linux-device-driver

I'm currently learning driver programming and am at very nascent stage. I'm unable to get the difference of use of [xHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Host_Controller_Interface), [EHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)#Enhanced_Host_Controller_Interface), or [OHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)#Open_Host_Controller_Interface) drivers and *usb_storage*.

When I plug my USB device ([pen drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_flash_drive)) and observe [dmesg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dmesg) output, it says that my device is using the `ehci` driver, but my device stops working when I `rmmod` *usb_storage*.

There are many drivers for different kind of USB devices let it be mouse, keyboard, camera, etc.

As of now, I assume that the xHCI driver is for USB host and the other driver is for the device we connect to our USB host. Am I correct? If not, what is the explanation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*HCI are specifications of USB hosts:

- [xHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Host_Controller_Interface) - for [USB 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0)
- [EHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)#Enhanced_Host_Controller_Interface) - for [USB 2.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_2.0)
- [OHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)#Open_Host_Controller_Interface) and [UHCI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_controller_interface_(USB,_Firewire)#Universal_Host_Controller_Interface) - for [USB 1.x](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB#USB_1.x)

*usb_storage* is a *upper level* driver working on the USB host side, and it is responsible for communication only with USB storage devices, not keyboard, mouse, etc.

The USB is maintained in form of a stack and **hci* drivers are the lowest level in that stack. *usb-storage* and other drivers are located on a higher level of this stack.